# Angular ui-select with tagging filters wrong

Tags: ui-select, angular-ui-select

When using AngularJS ui-select with `tagging`, the filter of `ui-select-choices` doesn't work as expected: the first item is missing.

Note that the model is an array of strings, not objects.

Any suggestions?

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/KmKzWJZNW4wGrVhXMIPA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0?p=preview) from the ui-select's github and I didn't see any working tagging input, **without** tagging label. It could be their problem but now, it's not possible to have a working tagging selector without tagging label.

so I think it can be better to remove the `tagging-label=""` .